# Class memoir Error: listing is not a counter

Tags: errors, numbering, listings, memoir, counters

I am trying to use `\counterwithout{listing}{chapter}`

1. [Chngcntr: \counterwithout not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45338/chngcntr-counterwithout-not-working)
2. [Number listings the same way as figures and tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316230/number-listings-the-same-way-as-figures-and-tables)

But memoir keeps complaining `Class memoir Error: listing is not a counter`

```latex
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}
\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithout{listing}{chapter}}

\begin{document}  % test5.tex:5: Class memoir Error: listing is not a counter.
\chapter{Hi}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Code,label=acode]
Code
\end{lstlisting}

Something...

\end{document}
```

Memoir code:

```latex
\newcommand{\@ifbothcntrs}[3]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}{% counter undefined
    \@memerror{#1 is not a counter}{\@eha}}%
  {% else counter is defined
    \@ifundefined{c@#2}{% within undefined
      \@memerror{#2 is not a counter}{\@eha}}%
    {% else both counter and within  are defined
     #3}}}

\newcommand{\counterwithin}{\@ifstar{\@csinstar}{\@csin}}
\newcommand{\@csinstar}[2]{%
  \@ifbothcntrs{#1}{#2}{\@addtoreset{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\@csin}[2]{%
  \@ifbothcntrs{#1}{#2}{\@addtoreset{#1}{#2}%
                        \@namedef{the#1}{\@nameuse{the#2}.\arabic{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\counterwithout}{\@ifstar{\@csoutstar}{\@csout}}
\newcommand{\@csoutstar}[2]{%
  \@ifbothcntrs{#1}{#2}{\@removefromreset{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\@csout}[2]{%
  \@ifbothcntrs{#1}{#2}{\@removefromreset{#1}{#2}%
                        \@namedef{the#1}{\arabic{#1}}}}
```

Comment: the name of the counter is lstlisting

Comment: Thanks! I see now that I should include the package `minted` (which defines the counter `listing`) instead of including the package `listings` (which defines the counter `lstlisting`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by [@Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer), instead of `listing`,

> the name of the counter is `lstlisting`